# Jenkins: How to show last build (not only last successful build) artifacts on job main page?

Tags: jenkins

By default jenkins shows the "last successful artifacts" on the jobs **main** page. This is ok most of the time. And I know how to configure the jobs to also store the artifacts in case of build failure.

But: In case of build failure the link to the artifacts of **the failed build** is only displayed as "build artifacts" on the **build** page of the job - not on the **main** page of the job. On the main page of the job there are still linked the "last successful artifacts" which come from an older build.

So what quite often happens: The developer gets the failure mail from jenkins, opens the job in jenkins and sees the jobs **main** page with the older successful artifacts. Because he does not realize this, he opens e.g. the dependency-check report to take a look at the error details - and wonders why there are no errors. This is sometimes quite confusing. The job reports an error, but the developer cannot see it - just because he opened the relevant artifact not from the **failed build** but from the **last successful build**.

So to make a long story short: How can I change the jobs **main** page to show not only the last successful artifacts but **also** **always** the artifacts of the **last** build - even if this was not successful. It should be the same link as on the jobs **build** page.

Comment: The expectation would normally be that unless successful, you don't expose the artifacts. In fact, if not successful, you usually don't have artifacts to expose! You can find the current /latest artifacts inside the Workspace (left menu and body), where they are built, unless you have Workspace cleanup plugin and enabled for failed builds.

Comment: Well, if artifacts are only relevant on success depends on the kind of artifact we talk about. In our case the "real" artifacts you might think about are (on success) always deployed to our artifact repository. What we need in jenkins in case of build failure are for example dependcy-check reports or trivy reports. All the stuff which is generated during build and contains the details about the failure. Because we build via pure docker build nodes, there is no workspace left after the build, so we need to archive the artifacts which might be relevant to understand the build failure.

Comment: I guess that speaks to the versatility of Jerkins, so many different ways to use it. I know there's a [Simple theme](https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-theme-plugin/) and [Login theme](https://plugins.jenkins.io/login-theme/) plugins, but I expect what you're looking for is probably hard-coded into the app. Not sure if you could apply some custom css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sidebar Link](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sidebar-link/) to add any link to the job's main page.

Provide the URL of the last build's artifacts, an appropriate name and image:
URL - http://JENKINS_SERVER_IP:8080/job/JOB_NAME/lastBuild/artifact
Text - Last Build Artifacts
Icon - /images/24x24/package.png

[image]

Comment: Nice plugin! But it doesn't help in my case, because I need a more generic solution, which does not require to be configured in each of our hundreds of jobs.

Comment: y, I know your suffer...